# Android Studio 0.8.2 URI has an authority component

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio

I am getting "Gradle project sync failed." when I start up Android Studio. When I try to clean the project, I get "Failed to complete Gradle execution    Cause: URI has an authority component"

I've tried several things already and am still stuck. I moved my config files out of my user folders and put them in my root directory where I have Android Studio. (C:/Studio). I've also tried to invalidate caches but that still didn't help. I'm on a networked VDI so I'm not sure if that might have something to do with it. Below is the message I'm getting from Gradle sync. Any ideas what can be going wrong here?

**Gradle Sync Message:**

Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.12/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read below process output to find out more:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
    at java.io.File.(File.java:423)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.EffectiveClassPath.findAvailableClasspathFiles(EffectiveClassPath.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.EffectiveClassPath.(EffectiveClassPath.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon.main(GradleDaemon.java:22)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only cause I've seen of this is if your home directory is on a network share (it has a Windows path of the form (\\UNC_PATH\... instead of something like C:\ for a local file). Gradle doesn't properly support that right now. There's a bug in Android Studio's bug database to track it:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56444

and it references a bug in Gradleware's bug database:

https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2941

The Android Studio bug report lists this as a workaround:

> I also faced same issue. Reason I figured out that may be when I
>   installed Android Studio with option -- Install to current User. This
>   step installed .gradle folder in the organization Network Path
>   [\{network}\users{USERID}.gradle]
>
> Resolution step: [On Windows 7 Machine]
>
> 1. Copied .gradle folder from path on network [\{network}\users{USERID}.gradle]  to [C:\Users{USERID}.gradle]
> 2. In Android Studio v-(Beta) 0.8.6 [File --> Settings] changed Gradle Settings
>
>    Global Gradle settings
>
>    Service directory path:  C:/Users/{USERID}/.gradle
>
>    Gradle VM options: -Dhttp.proxyHost={dummyHost} -Dhttp.proxyPort={dummyPort} -Dhttp.proxyUser={dummyUser} -Dhttp.proxyPassword={dummyPassword}
>
> I had also given Gradle VM options because it tried to download
>   Gradle-0.12+-all.jar before compiling.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, that was exactly what was happening. I thought the issue was with having the .AndroidStudioBeta file on the network drive so I moved that in the idea.properties file but I didn't know about the .gradle folder. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have a strong internet connectivity make sure you select the offline mode from the console. Selecting offline mode could solve the issue.

Comment: I went to settings and checked "Offline work" but I'm still getting the same error.