# From where is my Java code executing?

Tags: java, gradle, flashback

I've got a generic Java problem baked into a specific roadblock.

I am attempting to set up [Flashback](https://github.com/linkedin/flashback) on my Win10 box, but am hitting this stack trace on the command `./startAdminServer.sh -port 1234 --stacktrace`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:397)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClasspathUtil.getClasspathForClass(ClasspathUtil.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.installation.CurrentGradleInstallationLocator.findDistDir(CurrentGradleInstallationLocator.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.installation.CurrentGradleInstallationLocator.locateViaClass(CurrentGradleInstallationLocator.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.installation.CurrentGradleInstallationLocator.locateViaClassLoader(CurrentGradleInstallationLocator.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.installation.CurrentGradleInstallationLocator.locate(CurrentGradleInstallationLocator.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.installation.CurrentGradleInstallation.locate(CurrentGradleInstallation.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.installation.CurrentGradleInstallation.get(CurrentGradleInstallation.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon.main(GradleDaemon.java:22)
```

[Multiple](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2941) [searches](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/android-studio-gradle-issue/2327) have led to a ["Java/Gradle doesn't like UNC paths"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103564/android-studio-0-8-2-uri-has-an-authority-component) type answer. **My goal is to figure out which UNC path is being pulled back by this stack trace.**

I've peeled apart the stack trace (yay open source), but it gets at something about Java I don't currently understand. Specifically in [this file](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/7885810107702e52e7c6c5b260d5367b55799448/subprojects/base-services/src/main/java/org/gradle/internal/classloader/ClasspathUtil.java)

> CodeSource codeSource = targetClass.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();

Where `getProtectionDomain()` is part of [a system-level Java construct.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html)

**How do I troubleshoot which path getProtectionDomain is returning?**

- Is there a search order I am unaware of?
- Are there default env locations/variables under consideration? etc.

Considerations:

- I have cloned Flashback directly to `C:\` (i.e. the .jar I invoke is on `C:\`)
- I have Java 1.7.0_25-b17 installed (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
- I don't know what else is relevant here.

Comment: Perhaps you could get the process to open up a remote debug port and connect using eclipse/intellij and put a breakpoint at `java.io.File.java:397`